# Testing Vuex getters with argument returns undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chai, vuex

I have karma and chai setup and I am trying to follow the **Testing Getters** example [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/testing.html)

Here is my code for fruits.js store

```
// fruits.js store
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const fruits = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fruits: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Orange'}
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  getters: {
    getFruitById (state, {id}) {
      return state.fruits.find(fruit => {
        return fruit.id === id
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Here is my fruit.spec.js file

```
// fruit.spec.js
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { fruits } from '../../../../src/store/fruits'

describe('getters', () => {
  it('getFruitById()', () => {
    // mock data
    const state = {
      fruits: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Apricot'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Kiwi'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Watermelon'}
      ]
    }
    const id = 1
    // find fruit by id
    const result = fruits.getters.getFruitById(state, {id})
    expect(result).to.deep.equal([
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Apricot'
      }
    ])
  })
})
```

When I run my `fruit.spec.js` test it returns

`undefined is not a function`on line `const result = fruits.getters.getFruitById(state, {id})`

**The problem is that my mock state in `fruit.spec.js` is not passed in `fruit.js`**

How can I make the test pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to unit test your getters, you should export them separately:

```
// fruits.js store
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const getters = {
  getFruitById (state, {id}) {
    return state.fruits.find(fruit => {
      return fruit.id === id
    })
  }
}

export const fruits = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fruits: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Orange'}
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  getters,
})
```

This can then be accessed as following in the unit test:

```
import { getters } from '../../../../src/store/fruits'
// ...
    const result = getters.getFruitById(state, {id})
// ....
```